# Django site-wide cache, change top if authenticated

Tags: django, authentication, caching

I have a site where most of the pages are the same if you are authenticated or not.

If the user is authenticated the "Login" button is removed, and the username is displayed.

What is the easiest to way to change this without breaking the cache?

I was thinking I could do a ajax call to get the username from a page that is not cached, and save the username to localstorage.

But not sure if it is a good idea to to an extra server-hit if the user is not authenticated. How could I check if the user is authenticated without breaking the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the user login status -- `request.user.is_authenticated()` -- from the request made by the Ajax call. Then you return the username if user is authenticated and update the part of the DOM that displays username using Javascript. This should not affect your cache in any way.

Comment: What if I got 10 000 users that are not authenticated. Then I would have to to 10 000 extra ajax calls for every page they visited. Im not sure, but that does not seem like a good idea?

Comment: If the cost of making the ajax calls outweigh the benefits, you could simply leave the part that displays the username/login button uncached, and let the template engine work that out.

Comment: How do I leave that part uncached? ESI seems a bit extreme for this case.

Comment: What cache backend are you using? In any case, django's cache framework allows to cache fragments (or all) of your a template. See [Django's Cache Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)

Comment: I was thinking about using memcache for django (site-wide) and using varnish on top of that. I will try the ajax call, and see how the server holds up.